# Looking for a good git workflow for new projects with a small team

Tags: git, version-control

I work in a small team of developers (there are 3 of us).
in the research that I have done, the workflow that most teams seem to follow seems to be as follows a branch is created for a feature and then the branch is merged into master when coding on the feature is complete.

That seems to work well with mature projects where most of the code is already in place and a feature that one person work is separate from another, but with a new project developer really need to see each others changes as they are made and much of the work that needs to be done initially is "laying the foundations".

Are there any established patterns on how to manage the git workflow in this case? Would it make more sense for us to all work on the same branch and call it something like "initial_implementation" and then merge it into master when it reaches a reasonable level of maturity, and start working on feature branches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git workflow for small teams](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175034/git-workflow-for-small-teams)

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 0):

Usually teams work exactly as you found from your researches. In my experience, we always worked like that.

If you are going to work on a brand new project, you should structure your team's work by defining the project's requirements and scope first. You will then create all the tasks you need to work on, then each of you would work on different tasks creating a branch per each different task, merging them in master (or development, depending on your team's preferences) as soon as the code will be fully tested and the feature successfully reviewed.

If you all start working on the same branch without any structure, you'll end up having a project in very bad shape that someone will need then to completely refactor.

Comment: I’ve actually found the exact opposite to be better. Trunk based development can work insanely well for a disciplined team.

Comment: That's why you downvoted the answer? :)

Comment: Actually no. It’s because Scrum has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You're actually right, I've also edited the answer.